# The minimum value of a 32-bit signed integer?

Tags: integer, minimum

Why is not the minimum value like this:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: It's actually pretty clear what he's asking..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: [Use unsigned to get max value](http://ideone.com/366Zrb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a 3-bit example to keep things simple.

The value `0` represented as a 3-bit binary number is `000`.

If we subtract `1` from `0`, we get `-1`.  If we subtract `1` from `000`, we get `111` with a borrow that "falls off" because we only have 3 bits.

If we continue to subtract 1, we get:

```
-1  111
-2  110
-3  101
-4  100
```

If we start back at `0` and add `1`, we get the positive numbers:

```
+1  001
+2  010
+3  011
```

But when we try to add another `1`, we get the representation for `-4` instead of `+4`.

This is just like what would happen if you tried to wind back the odometer on your car.  Once you reached 0, the next number would be 9999999 (or however many digits there are on an odometer), but this can naturally be thought of as a representation of -1.  As you wind back even further, the number will move away from all 9's, but it would represent more negative values.  We could say that if the leftmost digit is between 0 and 4, then the number is positive, and if it is between 5 and 9, then it is negative.  As we continue to wind backwards, we will eventually reach 5000000, which is the most negative value.  Winding back once more causes an overflow because we get 4999999, which we consider to be positive (the most positive value). Incidentally, this is called 10's complement, and was used by Charles Babbage to represent negative numbers in his difference engine.

Answer (score 4):

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
↑
MSB is 1 indicating that the number is negative
```

Is actually -1. Why?

To calculate the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)  of a number, you flip all bits and add 1. Doing this to the number you proposed will give:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Which is 1, but the sign is negative. So you get -1.

You probably want to try:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

If you calculate the above number you'll get:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111    flip
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 +  add 1
-----------------------------------
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Which is indeed the minimal value.

Comment: What about systems or arch's which do not use 2's Complement?

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī I'm actually not sure about that.. Prefer someone who knows to answer you.

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī -- as `-2 < -1` that implies "11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111" would be smallest negative (as well as max positive) number that can be represent in 4-bytes. ...Although OP himself says 32-bit signed number.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this in terms of the "place value" of each bit. For the sake of space, let's consider an 8-bit signed integer for a moment, which can have values between -128 and +127.

The place values of each bit in this integer are, from least to most significant:

- +1 (LSB)
- +2
- +4
- +8
- +16
- +32
- +64 (MSB)
- -128 (sign bit)

This means that the highest value is represented as `01111111` (+127), and the lowest value is represented as `10000000` (-128). `11111111` represents -1.

The same principle applies to 32-bit signed integers, just with bigger place values (specifically, -2147483648 for the sign bit).

Answer (score 1):

In signed integers, the MSB represent the sign `1`=`-ve`, `0`=`+ve`.
So, the machine actually stores them in the range `0x00000000 - 0xffffffff`
But since it is `signed`, it has to include both the positive as well as the negative nos, and hence the **interpretation** changes it to `[-0x0fffffff + 1, 0x0fffffff]` or `[0x10000000,0x0fffffff]` in signed language.

The range is evenly split -  `[-2^31,2^31-1]`